# Обновление QTreeView при изменении данных

Tags: c++, qt

Есть класс, наследованный от `QAbstractItemModel` и `QTreeView` на основе этой модели. Модель строится на основе таблицы вида `id/name/parent_id` взятой из базы данных `MySQL`. Эта таблица сохраняется в конструкторе модели в `QList<TreeItem> list`, где `TreeItem` - структура, которая содержит поля `id`, `name`, `parent_id`. Есть кнопка, по нажатию которой в БД добавляется новая запись. Как можно реализовать автоматическую перерисовку дерева при добавлении новой записи в БД? Код модели:

```
TreeModel::TreeModel(QWidget *parent) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    CatProductsBL bl;
    list = bl.getTreeData();
}
QModelIndex TreeModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED (column);
    uint parent_id = parent.isValid() ? parent.internalId() : 0;
    QList<TreeItem> children;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.at(i).parent_id==parent_id)
            children.append(list.at(i));
    }
    int id = children.at(row).id;
    return createIndex(row, 0, id);
}
QModelIndex TreeModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
{
    //Получаем id родителя.
    uint parent_id;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.at(i).id==child.internalId())
            parent_id = list.at(i).parent_id;
    }
    if(parent_id==0)
        return QModelIndex();
    //Получаем место родителя в списке родителей того же уровня (row).
    //код родителя родителя
    uint parentOfParent_id;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.at(i).id==parent_id)
            parentOfParent_id = list.at(i).parent_id;
    }
    //список всех родителей, имеющих того же прародителя
    QList<TreeItem> parents;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.at(i).parent_id==parentOfParent_id)
            parents.append(list.at(i));
    }
    //определяем позицию row среди всех предков
    uint row;
    for(int i=0; i<parents.size(); i++){
        if(parents.at(i).id==parent_id)
            row=i;
    }

    return createIndex(row, 0, parent_id);
}
int TreeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    int childCount=0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.at(i).parent_id==parent.internalId())
            childCount++;
    }
    return childCount;
}
int TreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 1;
}
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role==Qt::DisplayRole){
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            if(list.at(i).id==index.internalId())
                return list.at(i).name;
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Почитал про emit dataChanged(). Попробовал добавить следующий код в класс модели:

```
void TreeModel::updateTree()
{
    list.clear();
    CatProductsBL bl;
    list = bl.getTreeData();
    emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex());
}
```

Вызывается этот метод при нажатии кнопки после добавления новой записи в БД. Но дерево не перерисовывается.

Comment: Вызовите ему refresh или repaint

Comment: Кому, QTreeView? repaint не помогает. Метода refresh у вьюшки нет.

Comment: Винда "кеширует" перерисовку. Сделайте `InvalidRect(окно_handle, rect=null, true)` оно сбросит кеш, а потом `repaint`. В WINAPI это помагает, на qt не писал...

Comment: Простите, но не то.

Comment: Работает, если вместо dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex()) эмитировать layoutChanged(). Не совсем понимаю отличия этих двух методов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда у вас добавляются строки в модель нужно использовать методы [beginInsertRows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) и [endInsertRows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows).

Добавление строки в конец будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
void Model::addRow(){
    int r = rowCount();      
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), r, r);

    // Добавляем одну строку в конец

    endInsertRows();
}
```

Если изменилась вся модель, нужны методы [beginResetModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel) и [endResetModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endResetModel)

Полное обновление модели выглядит так:

```
void Model::reset(){      
    beginResetModel();

    // Перечитываем все данные из бд

    endResetModel();
}
```

Аналогичные пары begin/end методов есть и для других случаев жизни ознакомиться с ними можете [здесь](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#protected-functions)

Comment: Спасибо, пара begin/endResetModel помогла! Добавил её в метод void TreeModel::updateTree(), между ними вписал код обновления списка QList, на основе которого строится модель. Получается теперь не нужно делать emit layoutChanged()? А в каких случаях тогда используются emit LayoutChanged() и emit dataChanged()?

Comment: `dataChanged` нужно использовать если данные изменились в уже существующей ячейке(редактирование). Про `layoutChanged` ничего сказать не не могу, так как его ввели в qt5, а я работаю с qt4. Как я понял из справки, этот сигнал нужен когда меняется порядок строк/столбцов, но сами данные не меняются(сортировка).